# How to add values of multiple filechooser to jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jfilechooser

I want to select multiple files from the file chooser and put those values in `JTable`. I tried it like this but same value is repeating on the `JTable`. In the printing line, it print the values correctly.

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
if (returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

   File file[] = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
   DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
   Vector v = new Vector();

   for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        String name;
        String path;
        long  size;
       name = file[i].getName();
       path = file[i].getPath();

       System.out.println("name = "+name+" path = "+path);

           v.add(name);
           v.add(path);
           dtm.addRow(v);;

          } 

    try {

    } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to be adding a new Vector each time - you need to move your Vector to inside your for loop.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
       Vector v = new Vector();
       String name;
       String path;
       long  size;
       name = file[i].getName();
       path = file[i].getPath();

       System.out.println("name = "+name+" path = "+path);
       v.add(name);
       v.add(path);
       dtm.addRow(v);;
       // rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JButton` as a cell editor, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor). Let the button's event handler evoke the `JFileChooser`. Update your `TableModel` to reflect the chosen file.